# Let user edit his own comment

Tags: comments, author, front-end, quick-edit

can I allow user to edit his own comment (without, username, url, or mail) on front-end. For example simple form on custom worpdress page with his comment and submit button.

Thank you all in advance!

Answer (score 3):

You can add the following code in function.php

```
$subscriber= get_role('subscriber');
$subscriber->add_cap('edit_comment');
```

Meanwhile `edit_comment` is only supported in version 3.1 or newer

Or you can use this plugin [link](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-ajax-edit-comments/)